# SQL Server Cursors, Loops and Set based Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, set, cursor

Using SQL Server to Select for each company in my NYSE table:

- Last Trade Price (from my Contracts table)
- Max Bid Price (from my Bids table)
- Min Ask Price (from my Asks table)

I've done it with a CURSOR and am researching a WHILE LOOP but in doing so many answers suggest SET BASED LOGIC (joins etc) can accomplish this.  However I don't see how set based logic can return MAX(TimePlaced) from the Contracts table in the same row as MAX(BidPrice) and MIN(AskPrice) from their tables.

Apologies for the pseudo code (it's actually much more complicated than this) and for being a noob -- is a better/practical solution for a Web App to populate each cell in the HTML output table via a separate query???

Comment: it would help if you can show sample data from all the tables involved? this is doable with a query.

Comment: From what you posted it definitely doesn't need a loop but provide a sample data set and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 tables, NYSE, Contracts, Bids, Asking.  Assuming all 4 tables have a Column CompanyId and that NYSE is the primary table (any companyid in the other tables will be in NYSE), this is easy using common table expression syntax.

```
;with Ct as (Select n.CompanyId, c.lastradeprice,
 row_number() over (partition by n.companyid 
                    order by tradedatetime desc) rw
      From nyse n inner join contract c on c.companyid =n.companyid),
Bd as (Select n.CompanyId, max(bc.bidprice) bidprice 
      From nyse n inner join bids b on b.companyid =n.companyid
      Group by n.companyid),
Ak as (Select n.CompanyId, min(a.askprice) AskPrice 
      From nyse n inner join asks a on a.companyid =n.companyid
      Group by n.companyid)
Select n.companyId, ct.lasttradeprice, bd.tradeprice, ak.AskPrice
From nyse n
    Left join ct on ct.companyid = n.companyId and rw=1
    Left join bd on bd.companyid = n.companyid
    Left join ak on ak.companyid = n.companyid
```

The join on contracts has an additional condition, as we want the latest price, not the greatest or the least, and so the results have to be broken down and ordered someho, which is what the partition and order by does.

The above query also contains the assumption that while an entry in nyse was required an entry in the other tables is optional.  If an entry in the other tables was mandatory, the query can be simplified even further.

Comment: I'll definitely try this and report back but even prior I wanted to reply with a huge thanks for the above and beyond effort in responding -- sincerely appreciated.

Comment: Awesome, your suggestion works great (I had looked at CTE previously but wasn't sure they provided what I wanted -- hence going down the CURSOR/LOOP track).

Comment: Hopefully not imposing but since you are acquainted with the basic hierarchy what is your opinion about de-normalizing the Contracts table? 

Specifically I currently have Contract.Price and Contract.Currency as duplicate entries of Bid.Price and Bid.Currency (note Contract.Shares is NOT the same as Bid.Shares since partial order fills are allowed).  

Is there any merit to this "for security" (i.e. all of Contract.Price and Bid.Price and Ask.Price must be the same)?  I realize it's an opinion I am asking for but thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate entries don't provide security, they in fact are a source of insecurity.  Having the data in two places means twice as many opportunities for the value to be set wrong.  Worse, if the values don't match, you will be encouraged to believe that one is correct, when it's just as likely that neither are correct. If you want a backup, then have a backup, either an audit table, backups or replication.  Having data in two places should be limited to foreign keys constraints and as required for performance (index views and equivalents).

Comment: Thanks again for the feedback.

Comment: You might want to look at windowing functions, I used cte's because I figured it would present a more familar format, only the calculation with Contract needed it -- the rest could have been done without a cte/subquery.